# Scene not rendering properly in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I created a floor in a scene and loaded a collada file(.dae) into my scene and tried to create a plane below that model. But I have problems like below.

[image]

This problem generates only when custom camera is used. Scene renders properly when system camera is used i.e if no custom camera is added
My code is as below:

> ```
> import UIKit import SceneKit
>
> class TestVC: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {
>
> var cameraNode: SCNNode!
> var modelNode: SCNNode!
> var scnView: SCNView!
> var camNode: SCNNode!
>
> var cameraPosition: SCNVector3!
>
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>     super.viewDidLoad()
>
>     scnView = SCNView(frame: self.view.frame)
>     scnView.delegate = self
>     view.addSubview(scnView)
>     scnView.delegate = self
>
>     let scene = SCNScene()
>     scnView.scene = scene
>
>     //camera
>     let camera = SCNCamera()
>     cameraNode = SCNNode()
>     cameraNode.camera = camera
>     camera.zFar = 1000
>     cameraPosition = SCNVector3(0, 100, 150)
>     cameraNode.position = cameraPosition
>     scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
>
>     //floor
>     let floor = SCNFloor()
>     floor.reflectivity = 0
>     let floorNode = SCNNode(geometry: floor)
>     let firstmaterial = SCNMaterial()
>     firstmaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/grass.jpg")
>     firstmaterial.diffuse.wrapS = SCNWrapMode.Repeat
>     firstmaterial.diffuse.wrapT = SCNWrapMode.Repeat
>     floor.materials = [firstmaterial]
>     scene.rootNode.addChildNode(floorNode)
>
>     let light = SCNLight()
>     let lightNode = SCNNode()
>     lightNode.light = light
>     light.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
>     light.color = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
>     scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
>
>     let light1 = SCNLight()
>     let light1Node = SCNNode()
>     light1Node.light = light1
>     light1Node.position = SCNVector3(0, 200, -100)
>     light1.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
>     scene.rootNode.addChildNode(light1Node)
>
>     let modelScene = SCNScene(named: "Barcelona Chair.dae")
>     let solNode = modelScene?.rootNode
>     solNode?.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-90), 0, 0)
>     scene.rootNode.addChildNode(solNode!)
>     scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
>
>     let plane = SCNPlane(width: 100, height: 100)
>     let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
>     planeNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float(M_PI_2), 1, 0, 0)//(CGFloat(M_PI_2), 1, 0, 0)
>     planeNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 1, 0)
>     plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()
>     scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
>
> }
> ```

Comment: That could be a problem specific to this dae. Did you try another model? Are you running iOS 8 or 9 ? Using the Metal renderer or GL renderer?

Comment: Yes, I did try other models as well but result is the same. Problem happens in both iOS 8 and iOS 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why the above problem exists but I got a different way of doing the thing. You can use SCNShape to draw an overlay over a floor. I drew a rectangular path using UIBezierPath and set the path property of the SCNShape class. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably seeing is known as "z-fighting".  Basically, your floor and your plane are coexisting - they are coplanar - so the rendering of them is ambiguous.  Try lifting the plane up a little by setting its position higher than the floor plane, and you should see this problem go away.

Comment: Yeah, I already brought the red plane above the floor but problem is same. I added some details to my questions. I found out the alternative to this but if you got any reason why this happens then plz add your answer. Thank You

Comment: Well, it's possible you didn't bring it up *enough*.  Depending on your "far" setting, the camera may not have enough precision to render it properly (i.e., it may not see the difference between the two elevations).  I'd try bringing it up quite a bit further and seeing if it works, and then experimenting with your "near" and far" settings.  Also, if the situation only occurs in custom cameras, I'd look at other settings for the cameras, or just repurpose the default camera.